# running same Keybindings in vscode for python and Jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set up my Jupyter binding keys to run the current cell just as I run a python file in the terminal. I thought that by giving a when clause to Jupiter when the file/cell is focused would allow vscode to decide in which context the same Keybinding should be used, but apparently that is not working. Here is a pic of the when clause in both cases.

[image]

It would be great to use ctrl+enter in both situations but I am bit lost on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the When clause for the python file to the following

resourceExtname == '.py'

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Answer (score -1):

"Search for run python in terminal and click the Python: Run Python File in Terminal. Create a keyboard shortcut sequence that works for you." You can set the keybindings to **ctrl+enter**.  [Source](https://jasonmurray.org/posts/2020/vscodeplay/)

Comment: that is really unrelated to the problem.